# Compile error when comparing between named type and unamed type

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(template.HTML("test") == "test")

    htmlString := "test"
    fmt.Println(template.HTML("test") == htmlString)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/dON4eLpGN8

document for `template.HTML`:
http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML

The first comparison is `true`. However, the second comparison yield following error :

> invalid operation: "html/template".HTML("test") == htmlString
>   (mismatched types "html/template".HTML and string)

Can someone explain what happened under the hood ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, second expression is invalid their types are incompatible.

Every operations in Go, arguments are must be same type. The second expression

```
template.HTML("test") == htmlString
```

is invalid since it's comparing `template.HTML` and `string`. Although `template.HTML` is driven from `string`, but it is incompatible. You should cast the variable like `template.HTML(htmlString)`.

But the first expression

```
template.HTML("test") == "test"
```

is valid because the type of constant "test" interpreted as `template.HTML`. Untyped constant has default type, but it can be any driven type by context at compile time. [This article](http://blog.golang.org/constants) explains about constant in detail. Maybe this article make your question clear.